# How do I add the p value on the hover of a plotly express heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, correlation, p-value

With SciPy I get the Spearman correlation and p-values.

[image]

With px.imshow from plotly express I get the following plot:

[image: Heatmap plot]

At this moment the hover shows: **Feature_1**, **Feature_2** and their respective **Correlation**.

How do I make the hover also show the **p_value**?

Comment: I suggest adding p-value instead of the correlation value because the correlation value is represented by the color and its value can be easily read from colorscale.

Comment: Please add a little of your data or at least dummy data to your question to let others help you.

Comment: Thank you Hamza. I already did it with plotly.figure_factory.create_annotated_heatmap, but I want it to be a last option. I would like the label to be the value of the correlation and the p_value to appear on hover.

Comment: Great! Try to add some data by writing df.head().to_dict() and copy the result to your question.

Comment: {'Feature_1': {0: 'Buttinia type', 1: 'Buttinia type', 2: 'Buttinia type', 3: 'Buttinia type', 4: 'Buttinia type'}, 'Feature_2': {0: 'Diporopollis aff. assamica', 1: 'Esporas, hifas y/o cuerpos fructiferos', 2: 'Forro de foraminífero', 3: 'Sphaeromorpho', 4: 'Scolecodonte'}, 'Correlation': {0: 0.15017236275035822, 1: 0.10568101029288535, 2: 0.11313837651615352, 3: 0.18552770543488992, 4: -0.07524115817860574}, 'p_value': {0: 0.4736830359134445, 1: 0.6151298916911316, 2: 0.590256326534067, 3: 0.37459950669497644, 4: 0.7207528713018001}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of `plotly.figure_factory.create_annotated_heatmap`, you will not find any attribute to change the hover data. Thus, I suggest using  `plotly.graph_objects` as follows:

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

z = np.round(np.random.rand(5,5),2)
p = np.round(np.random.rand(5,5),2)
    
feature_1 =  ['Buttinia1 type',
      'Buttinia2 type',
      'Buttinia3 type',
      'Buttinia4 type',
      'Buttinia5 type']

feature_2 = ['Diporopollis aff. assamica',
     'Esporas, hifas y/o cuerpos fructiferos',
     'Forro de foraminífero',
     'Sphaeromorpho',
     'Scolecodonte']

hovertext = np.empty(z.shape, dtype=object)

for i, ftr2 in enumerate(feature_2):
    for j,ftr1 in enumerate(feature_1):
        hovertext[i,j] = f'feature 1: {ftr1}<br />feature 2: {ftr2}<br />Correlation: {z[i,j]}<br />p-value: {p[i,j]}'      

fig= go.Figure(go.Heatmap(z=z,
                          x=feature_1,
                          y=feature_2,
                          hoverinfo='text',
                          hovertext=hovertext,
                          texttemplate="%{z}"))
fig.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

You can define features 1 nd 2 by using `df.feature1.unique().tolist()`